# Using .NET code to enforce granular data acess in SSRS

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services

Here's a question that my team and I have been scouring the internet for help for, with little success.  It sounds like (in our minds) a common situation and zeroing in on the best approach could be very useful for many.

We have an ASP.NET application that uses .NET code to control data access at a fairly granular level.  That is, we have a user table, a role table, security tables, workflow tables, then lots of business data tables.  Access to business data is highly-configurable by the end user, as they can self-administer user accounts and security directly in the application.  Our .NET C# code determines what data a particular request is entitled to (based on Windows login), and serves it.  There is no relevant business security using SQL Server logins/roles.

So, **how does one implement SSRS into a system that uses .NET code to programmatically enforce data access as defined in relational data?**

We think our solution would look like one of the following:

[SSRS Report] > [Datasource] > our .NET code that controls data access > [SQL Server] 
...or... 
[SSRS Report] > our .NET code that controls data access > [Datasource] > [SQL Server]

If this is correct, then what technology or concept are we missing to make this possible?

Any solution should meet these key requirements:

1. Business power users (report creators) should be able to create SSRS reports using Report Builder 3.0.  They should still be able to work with business data and relationships using Dataset Design View and Query Designer.
2. Business power users (report creators) should not have to implement data access into their reports or data queries.  They should only have to worry about report design.
3. End users (report consumers) accessing the report, will get filtered data (done by .NET code) in their report based on their specific level of access.

Surely someone else out there is using .NET code to manage data access--is SSRS not an option in this scenario?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar situation for our ASP.Net MVC application where the RESTful web services pass back XML or JSON data to the front end applications.

For reporting, we wanted to call these same controllers to get the same data. Fortunately SSRS is amazingly extensible. I created a [custom data processing extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152816%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) that calls our ASP.Net MVC controllers and returns the data, which is deserialised into datasets for use in the reports.

My queries then look like this:

```
Action=SomeAction;Controller=ControllerName;DtoType=List<MyDto>
```

While not trivial, it isn't as hard as you might think and implementing a custom data processing extension is a good way to solve your problem. There are plenty of examples online to get you started.

Comment: Thanks Chris, this is really helpful.  Do you have any comments on performance?  Is there a cost/overhead using data processing extensions on retrieving your data?

Comment: I found the performance quite good. Deserialising the data doesn't add too much of an overhead. The key is the performance of the web services. If the data returned by your .Net code is already structured well - XML or JSON - then you should have no problems.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS works well because it is so close to the database.  Trying to insert a .NET layer between the database and itself is not going to work very well.

You have user, role, and security tables in the database, and [SSRS will tell you User!UserID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255216.aspx) for the Windows user.  If you are willing to reimplement your data access logic, you could write a T/SQL stored procedure that accepts the UserID as an argument and filters the returned data.  The stored procedure is the dataset for your report.

It will be a little more difficult to give business power users the ability to create their own reports.  You could do this by implementing a series of stored procedures that return general datasets for the use of these power users when they are building their reports.  The procedures are then functioning as filtered views against the underlying table data.  When report consumers run the resulting reports, they will see data that has been filtered according to their own UserID.